# What are the best ways to wrap C function and function pointer in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project with openGL, and I want to wrap all the C function, function pointers with a higher level of abstraction using C++ STL and boost. I checked `boost::function`, but it was designed to work with functor instead of function pointers. I wonder if there is a C++ idiom help to wrap C function calls instead of using it globally. Any idea?

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: It would be better if you told us what *exactly* you want to do. The approach you mention in your question sounds smelly to me.

Comment: @dark_charlie: I'm still vague what do I want to achieve. The idea came up because I realize that glut uses all C function pointers. Anyways thanks!

Comment: Then perhaps some well written frameworks such as Irrlicht or Ogre3D could work better for you. Have you considered them?

Comment: @dark_charlie: My motivation was only for educational purposes. So I want to think of a way to handle C function instead of using existing C++ framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boost Function also works with function pointers see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html#id1264511

Answer (score 3):

`boost::function` works perfectly well with function pointers. It can operate on any type with an `operator()` of the correct signature- including function pointers.

Comment: I would have thought the whole point of operator() and functors is to allow interchangability for functions and functors.

Comment: @Keith: It does- at compile-time. `boost::function` enables it at run-time.